# Division remainder return 2 zero

Tags: php

Modulus (%) operator return single zero. It is correct but i want to 2 zero after using modulus (%) operator. I don't want to use **if** condition.

```
$k = 60;
$result = $k%60;
echo "Result = ".$result;
```

Output
**Result = 0** 
Expected output 
**Result = 00**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it :

```
$k = 60;
$result = $k%60;
echo str_pad($result, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

or test this method  :

```
$result=0
$pad_length = 2;
$pad_char = 0;
$str_type = 'd'; // treats input as integer, and outputs as a (signed) 
decimal number


$format = "%{$pad_char}{$pad_length}{$str_type}"; 

// output and echo
printf($format, $result);
```